# How to find out the owner of a record where the object has two master detail relationships

Tags: sharing, detail

I have a custom object which has two master detail relationships. One to Opportunity and one to another custom object. It is on the detail side.

I'm trying to determine which parent object will provide ownership for the detail record as a result of the Master Detail relationship. Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary parent, i.e. the  relationship that was created first, is the one that will set the ownership of the child record. It also controls the look and feel of the child record.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the object was imported via change set. Both fields were created at the same time.

Comment: In the org, it would appear as though they would have been created at the sae time, but in the sandbox, there still would have been a primary and a secondary established at the time of their creation that should show up in your schema or metadata someplace in your org.

Comment: The sandbox will have been deleted by now but I'll see if I can find out somewhere else. Thanks for your help